# jQuery Smooth Sliding DIV Height

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, slideup, slidedown

I have a Div that is 400px in height with the ID "content", I then do a slideToggle on the Div, load some data into the Div of a varying height e.g. 200px, and then do another slideToggle. What I get is the slide expanding to 400px, then jump back to 200px. And the same in reverse, expanding to 200px, then jump to 400px.

This is my code:

```
$('#content').slideToggle(600, function() {
    $("#content").load('data.php').slideToggle(600);
});
```

So I thought I could do something like this, which would slide up the content Div, load the data, and then after it's loaded slide back down. This doesn't jump like the above method, but it is quite jerky for some reason.

```
$('#content').slideUp(600, function() {
    $("#content").load('data.php', function() {
        $("#content").slideDown(600);
    });
});
```

Can anybody tell me if there is a better way of doing this so that I can slide it smoothly?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using jQuery version 1.4.2.

Comment: the missing single quotes after the data.php is just in this question, right ? not in the actual code..

Comment: Does the slideUp/Down enable and disable the scrollbars ? Firefox has some issues with animating divs and at the same time recalculating the scrollbar size.. Does the jerkiness appear in all browsers ?

Comment: Fixed missing quote was just on my example. My second code example seems to be the best I can get it, it just seems to be a little jerky in both FF 3.6, and IE8, like a flickering of the content Div before the slideDown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#content').slideUp(600, function() {
    $("#content").load('data.php', function() {
        $("#content").slideDown(600);
    });
});
```

This produces the best results.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem.  I was able to correct this issue by setting the div height before sliding up.

Example:

```
$("#myDiv").height($("#myDiv").height());
$("#myDiv").slideUp();
```